# Extension 'cogs.test' raised an error: CommandRegistrationError: The command test is already an existing command or alias

Tags: python, discord.py

Can anyone help me fix this error I'm making a discord bot.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('test')

    def setup(client):
        client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "setup" function should not be in your class. It cannot be called directly if it is.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('test')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

This should work